# Creating binary matrix for threshold as a result of matrix multiplcation

Tags: linear-algebra

I have an unknown matrix.
I need to multiply it by a 2nd matrix.
The result of this multiplication should be a binary matrix of values greater than threshold t as 1 and smaller as 0.

For example:
Display all values greater than 100 as 1, and others as 0.

```
Unknown Matrix M1    Result R
|100|99 |100|        |0|0|0|
|13 |100|112|   ==>  |0|0|1|
|0  |150|2  |        |0|1|0|
```

What is M2 (the matrix that I will multiply M1 by) needs to be?

A broader example:

```
        Create Matrix for values larger than t
M1                    R
|<t|=t|>t|            |0|0|1|
|<t|<t|>t|  *  M2 =   |0|0|1|
|>t|<t|=t|            |1|0|0|
```

My question is my first step to figure out how to solve this issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41517564/monochrome-filter-in-svg-ideally-snap-svg

Comment: Are you comfortable with row-reduction?

Comment: The particular context in which I need this question solved does not allow me to perform any actions on the matrix except multiplications.

Comment: Row operations can be expressed via matrix multiplication, if that changes anything

Comment: I'm open to hear what your thinking of. Maybe it will get my on the right path. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to express such an operation with a matrix multiplication:

let the threshold be 3, and 
$$
M_1=
\begin{pmatrix}
4 & 2\\
2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
you want to obtain 
$$
M_1M_2= R =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
but if $v=(v_1,v_2)$ is the first column of $M_2$, then

(1° row, 1° column)
$$ 4v_1 + 2v_2 = 0 $$
(2° row, 1° column)
$$ 2v_1 + v_2 = 1 $$
that are incompatible.

Comment: Maybe I am failing to express my issue in a strictly mathematical way. Forgive me, I am not a mathematician, but this is what I am after:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41517564/monochrome-filter-in-svg-ideally-snap-svg